# How to put a large message onto WebSphere MQ queue through a TCL script?

Tags: tcl, ibm-mq

I am trying to put a large file onto a WebSphere MQ queue through a TCL script. Following is what I have at the moment:

```
exec sh -c "echo $msg | qmqsput targetQueue queueManager
```

However I run into the following error:

```
Couldn't execute "sh": argument list too long
```

My message is very large and is larger than the max argument length. How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to go via sh, so just try this:

```
exec qmqsput targetQueue queueManager << $msg
```

Comment: Definitely the best option here.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the message to a file first.

```
set fn tmsg[pid].txt
set fh [open $fn w]
puts $fh $msg
close $fh
exec sh -c "cat $fn | qmqsput ..."
catch { file delete $fn }
```